# ExactOnline - Error 403: Forbidden - The division is blocked

Tags: exact-online

I am using ExactOnline API to fetch the transactions, my API is working fine, but suddenly the **Error 403: Forbidden - The division is blocked**  error occurs and API return the empty result.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 403 with reason "The division is blocked" typically means the administration is temporarily blocked by a process that needs exclusive access to the administration. Examples are:

- One of the company's users is creating or restoring a backup of the administration.
- Exact is moving the administration to a different database. (After office hours; users are notified in advance through Exact Online's workflow system.)

API clients should be able to handle this situation. The typical solution is to try again at a later time.

You can find a full list of response codes here:
https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-respcodeserrorhandling